# Отладка проекта в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, jetbrains

Моя задача запустить под отладчиком проект на Django в PyСharm.

Условия.

- Ubuntu 13.04, python 2.7
- Я запускаю IDE от своего пользователя (к примеру, niсk).
- Для обращения к базе данных используется Postgres пользователь www-data.
- При запросе странички скрипт выполняется от пользователя www-data, затем идет запрос к базе.

Для того, чтобы все работало я запускаю приложение используя след. команду:

```
sudo -u www-data  python manage.py runserver test_domain.ru:8000
```

Посмотрев настройки PyCharm я не нашел опцию для того, чтобы задать от какого пользователя необходимо запустить скрипт. Как следствие появляется ошибка (так как PyCharm запущен от пользователя nick, а запрос обрабатывается от www-data):

> OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "www-data"

Решил попробовать в обход - использовать удаленную отладку - запустить на локальном ПК скрипт от нужного пользователя и приотачиться к нем PyCharm'ом (опять же, не нашел типичной для VS опции "присоединиться к процессу"). Настройку делал в соответствии с руководством http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/

Во время запуска выдает следующею ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/engine/manage_debug.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pydev import pydevd
ImportError: No module named pydev
```

Я выставил `PYTHONPATH`, установил `pycharm-debug.egg` (`easy_install pycharm-debug.egg`), импортирую пути `sys.path.append('/development/ide/pycharm-2.7.3/pycharm-debug.egg')`, но ничего не помогает.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить ошибку импорта, а также каким способом задать пользователя, от которого запуск будет запускаться `manage.py`?

PS Был бы рад ответу от [@crazycoder](/users/12193/crazycoder).

*Обновление*

На рабочем сервере проект работает через `mod_wsgi + apache`, а это означает, как я понимаю, что скрипт будет выполняться от пользователя www-data.

Answer (score 2):

или можно просто добавить пользователя nick в группу www-data, если это не скомпрометирует безопасность

и вообще не совсем понятен сам юзкейс запуска **dev** сервера от пользователя www-data и при чем это к тому, что в постгресе заведен такой пользователь

Comment: >На рабочем сервере проект работает через mod_wsgi + apache, а это означает, как я понимаю, что скрипт будет выполняться от пользователя www-data.

ок. и какое отношение это имеет к dev-серверу?

Comment: Добавления пользователя `nik`, в группу `www-data` не помогло. Плиз, подскажите в чем вы видете ошибку запуска под отладчиком?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, если ваш пользователь добавлен в группу, то нет смысла запускать дев-сервер через судо -- от вашего пользователя он должен будет запуститься с теми же правами

Comment: Как я понимаю, запрос будет всегда выполняться от `www-data`, так как пришел из веба. Изменение группы пользователя `nick` не дало эффекта. Как мне кажется, одним из выходов будет создание домашней папки для `www-data`, тогда я смогу запустить `PyCharm` от его имени.

Comment: уфф.. я кажется бессилен, но попробую еще раз:
1) на дев-сервере _нет_ разницы, то какого юзера он запущен
2) базе вообще пофиг то, от какого _системного_ юзера запущен клиент, имеет значение только под каким юзером _базы_данных_ клиент к ней коннектится (т.е. в данном контексте -- логин/пароль к базе в settings.py)